# Hide collapse panel title when collapsible panel in ExtJs

Tags: extjs

Hide collapse panel title when collapsible panel is collapse in.

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'panel',
    reference: 'mypanel',
    padding: '0 15px',
    scrollable:true,
    width: 300,
    userCls: 'collapsible-panel border-right',
    title: 'My Panel',
    collapsible: {
         direction: 'left',
         collapsed: true,
         dynamic:true
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any such inbuilt method to achieve this. You can use `collapse` and `expand` events to do so.

```
listeners: {
     collapse: function() {
         this.setTitle('');
     },
     expand: function() {
          this.setTitle('My Panel');
     }
}
```

I have created a working fiddle for you [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/33bd)